# Why am I not getting prompt for passphrase on other computer in ssh? Only getting password prompt without passphrase

Tags: ssh, openssh, passphrase

`root@Harshit:~# ssh root@my-ip`

`root@my-ip's password:`

Comment: A *passphrase* is typically used to decrypt a system, usually at boot. In order to use ssh, the system must already be booted and decrypted. Perhaps you mean some kind of password that does not involve decryption?

Answer (score 0):

```
root@Harshit:~# ssh root@my-ip
```

You are logging in with `ssh` on the server `my-ip` as the user `root`. Thus, the server knows the user, and accordingly only asks the password next:

```
root@my-ip's password:
```

That is for the "why". There is no need to ask for the user again.

Remove the part `root@` from the first command to have the server ask you both username and password.